# Where is CORE Joomla! 2.5 Menu Item Type?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Recently, I've try to upload a new module into our website, but after a fail "unable to install all the components", we are now unable to manage the website cause all the Menu Type Item disappear — and by the same time, make the website down.

So where can I find the core "menu item type" to remplace and try make all this work fine.

[image: Menu Item Type GONE !!!! :(]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before you starting trying to edit Core Joomla files to try and fix things....**dont!** I have told many people that editing core Joomla files can results in security issues, prevent other functions from working, get overridden on a Joomla update and more.

What I would try first, it download a fresh copy of Joomla 2.5, and extract only the following folders:

1. Administrator
2. Includes
3. Libraries

Then, zip them up, upload via the FTP to the root folder and extract.

Answer (score 0):

It's highly unlikely that this is a result of any core files being changed. The menu item types is a dynamically created list based on the various views that are available and set up to be menu item types in the installed components.

The first thing you should do is go and remove any of the files that the extension you tried to install left in your file system. Most likely, one of those files is causing the function that builds the menu item types to break when it gets to that component. Remove the issue and your will likely get the rest of your menu types back.

Also, Lodder is absolutely correct. There is never any reason to edit a Joomla core file. You can accomplish anything you want through overrides and extensions, there is never a need to edit core files.