# Fatal error: Call to undefined method JUserHelper::verifyPassword()

Tags: php, sql, joomla, call, undefined

Today as normal I was try to access my Joomla back-end and when I typed Login and Password I received message:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method JUserHelper::verifyPassword() in /home/my_site/public_html/plugins/authentication/joomla/joomla.php on line 56

I have no idea how it was happen as I site has work normally since this time. Front end working perfectly, just can't access my administrator area. I am using Joomla 2.5.

Comment: Error says it all. You have no defined method verifyPassword(), and you are trying to call it in joomla.php on line 56. I guess you have no idea what it means? Btw, "Sorry if I make this topic doubled!" - you **should** show some search effort of your own.

Comment: I tried find an answer before I asked - believe me... I am not kind of person who looking for the easiest way - just to get ready solution. I know that people on this website are experienced as I am using this site a lot to solve my issues.

Comment: How can I fix that issue? Are you able to help? Thanks

Comment: Have you made any changes to any core Joomla files? I would suggest you follow my instructions I gave to another user on a different question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12861492/where-is-core-joomla-2-5-menu-item-type/12861910#12861910

Comment: No worries :) I've added this as a proper answer to benefit other who may have the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

I'll write this as a proper answer incase anyone else has the same issue.

It would seem you have either made a core file change or there is a core file missing. Either way, the function is missing.

So what I would do first, is download a fresh copy of Joomla 2.5, and extract only the following folders:

- Administrator
- Includes
- Libraries

Then, zip them up, upload via the FTP to the root folder and extract.